# Python setuptools: a package not installed even when found through find_packages

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils

I'm trying to build a package having the following structure:

```
main-dir/
    setup.py
    package/
        __init__.py
        bar/
            __init__.py
        baz/
            __init__.py
    package_foo/
        __init__.py
        boo/
            __init__.py
```

Using `find_packages()` in `setup.py` I get the correct list of packages, something like:

```
[
    'package',
    'package.bar',
    'package.baz',
    'package_foo',
    'package_foo.boo',
]
```

However, when I install the package, I only get `package` installed in the `site-packages` directory, and `package_bar` is nowhere in sight. Even more strange, if I rename the `package` dir (to, say, `packagee`), it doesn't get installed too.

Just to be clear, I'm trying to get both `package` and `package_foo` installed on the top level of `site-packages`, like this:

```
import package
import package_foo
```

Any suggestions which route to go?

UPDATE: I need to clarify that the issue happens only when I upload the package to a `devpi` server I run  locally; a `python setup.py build` correctly creates both packages in the `build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/` directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've managed to figure out the issue: it turns out that `devpi upload` by default uses any versioning control system it finds in the package, and builds the distribution from there. Since my changes were not yet committed it kept building from the old code, which didn't include the `package_foo` directory. Luckily an option to ignore versioning is provided, so the correct command to use is:

```
devpi upload --no-vcs
```

Of course, I plan to have the package properly versioned for the final release, but still need to build and upload a distribution during development.